# Add button on Android Gmail inbox screen

Tags: android, button, gmail, screen, addition

I would like to add a new button on Android Gmain Inbox screen:
1) is it possible to do this?
2) if yes how to proceed?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to do that on the Gmail app on Android, then the answer is no.

You cannot inject code into other apps, that would be a huge security breach.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply Udinic...So what about if I would like to add a custom item-menu when the end-user press the phone menu button?

Comment: the menu is also considered to be a "code", so the answer here is the same.

Comment: What is the best and easy way to add a contextual menu fot Gmail inbox ?

Comment: Do you thing it is possible to detect an intent which indicate the end-user has selecting (checkbox checked) the fist mail from inbox?

Comment: I don't think there's an intent thrown in that case.